# Should I set up a user per site on my server?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I recently purchased a dedicated server. I have multiple websites that I'd like to host on this server. Is there any reason to set up a new user for each site, or is it ok to put all the sites under one user?

It's a debian system running Apache2.

Comment: No, i would not think of any reason to do that to be frankly.

Comment: Depends on how paranoid you are from a security point of view.  Do you need a high level of certainty that the two sites won't interfere with each other's data?

Comment: Nope, not worried about security at that level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to do this.  [Virtualhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) exist to separate websites from each others' namespace.

Comment: Hacked Wordpress, can write to any other website's folder. Account isolation with limited write permissions per website would stop this.

Comment: I don't see how, as the hacker would have the privileges of the apache user.

Comment: @Sirex, completely depends on the web server setup.  It is completely possible to configure a web server to have the scripts in a particular virtual host, run with the credentials unique to that virtual host. See suphp.org for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely a need to do this, if you are running several sites on a internet facing web server. The primary benefit is compartmentalization. Meaning, when one site is compromised...ONLY that site is compromised. The alternative is someone finding a weaker site, and gaining access to all of them from that.

Setup different users for each site, and configure permissions to be as restrictive as practical. If cross-site access to files is needed, take a look at POSIX ACL's (setfacl/setfacl, etc.) for permissions beyond user/group. Then use something like suexec, mpm-itk, or various module specific options (for example, modwsgi allows this) to run the site as the correct user.

If your site faces the internet, someone WILL attempt to hack you... several times a day, more than likely. Don't skimp on security (especially if you host any user data)!